# Will it break SOLID principle?

Tags: oop, generics, design-patterns, solid-principles, gosu

I'm trying to write a generic method which get called and based on object type it should set indicators.

1. Will it break any solid principles?
2. Is there a better way of doing it?

I was working on one of the features where I have 3 lines of business like Car, Van and Bike.

I have `IVehicle` interface which is handling all the common implementation between the 3 lines of business.

Now, I have to set two common indicator `Car` and `Van` but for `Bike`, I want to set some different indicator. I want to create an object of this class once but it handle based on type of line business.

If write this method like this will it break any SOLID principles? If it is incorrect, can you please suggest an alternative?

Note: `INDICATOR_B` should be true in all LOB

```
function populateIndicator() {
  if (_motorObject typeis Car or _motorObject typeis entity.Van) {
    _motorObject.INDICATOR_A = true
  }

  if (_motorObject typeis Bike) {
    _motorObject.INDICATOR_C = true
  }

  _motorObject.INDICATOR_B = true
}
```

Comment: whatever programming language this is, it does not look like java

Comment: edited the language but added java for better reach @GyroGearless

Comment: is _motorObject passed in any way as parameter to this object or the class owning the method?

Comment: This should be a polymorphic method *in* IVehicle.

Comment: @DavidGuida _motorobject is coming from abstract class. I have created a abstract on top of my implementation class.

Comment: sorry, but the design is not clear. Would you mind updating your original post and include more details?

Comment: also, without entering too much into the reasoning, you could evaluate replacing all those boolean INDICATOR_X with a single enum.

Answer (score 0):

Short version: use polymorphism to implement `populateIndicator` method.

Checking types in the base class breaks Liskove substitution principle. If you have a duplicate code for assigning like  `_motorObject.INDICATOR_B = true` you can use template method pattern.

```
abstract class VehicleBase{

   public void populateIndicator(){

      conceretePopulateIndicator();
      // common code for all derived classes
      _motorObject.INDICATOR_B = true;
   }

   protected abstract void conceretePopulateIndicator();

}

public class Bike: VehicleBase{

    protected override void conceretePopulateIndicator(){
        _motorObject.INDICATOR_C = true
    } 
}
```

this design won't break any rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rule factory here. You can define three rules. Each rule will accept type which will have one of two values Four Wheeler/Two Wheeler. You can set indicator accordingly in rule. It will not break SOLID principle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will break open-closed principle.

You can create interface with `function populateIndicator()` and default implementation `_motorObject.INDICATOR_B = true` And other classes Car, Van, Bike in you case should implement interface and override default method in their own way in case it applicable